# file is not uploaded while sending mail with attachment in vb

Tags: vb.net, email, file-upload, smtp, uploading

i tried uploading text files using the following vb code,

```
Sub mail()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "password")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    mail.To.Add("mymail@gmail.com")
    mail.From = New MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com")
    mail.Subject = "files"
    mail.Body = "most secure"
    'mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("d:\b.txt"))
    mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("d:\c.txt"))
    'mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("d:\a.txt"))
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
End Sub
```

i tried uploading all three files, file a(5kb) and b(2kb) are getting uploaded but file c(126kb) is not getting uploaded, then i tried uploading only c file but mail is sent without c file. is this error is caused due to file size?? how can i solve this issue??

Comment: Set a breakpoint on attachments.add then F10 once and make sure your attAchment is indeed added. Are there any errors?

Comment: You should probably remove the On Error Resume Next so you know what the error is

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR i mean that other small files are sent, only c file which is 126kb files size is not uploaded, if i place any other smaller file it is being sent. is that due to any memory problem??

Comment: It shouldn't be a memory issue, that's relatively a small file. Is it indeed a text file? Also what happens when you set a breakpoint where you're adding the attachment, Also is that file read only by chance?